# Python connection pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a problem on my mind. Now when I start with pymongo flask will it try to reconnect to mongodb on every request or will it make a single connection?

It’s a simple question but I just started I want to learn.

```
from flask import Flask
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("atlas-uri")
db = client["myFirstDatabase"]
mycol = db["customers"]
```

Will such a code send a constant request to connect to mongodb on every browser request with flask?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on when/how you create the client. If your client is persisted across requests,  connections it makes will persist also.